# Normal Subgroups of a Nilpotent Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite nilpotent group with order n. Is it necessarily true that for all divisors m of n, G contains a normal subgroup H such that ord(H)=m? Why or why not? I was able to show that G always contains a subgroup H such that ord(H)=m. But I cannot show it if the additional condition of normality is imposed.

Comment: You can do this inductively. Quotient out by a central subgroup of order p, then consider separately the case of p dividing m or not. The latter requires the fact that characteristic<normal implies normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result follows from these lemmas.  Let $G$ be a finite nilpotent group.

Lemma 1. All Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are normal.

Lemma 2. The group $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Lemma 3. In any finite $p$-group, there exists a normal subgroup having size equal to any power of $p$ dividing the order of the group.

Lemma 4. If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then any $p$-subgroup of $G$ normalizes any $q$-subgroup of $G$.  (This follows from Lemma 2.)

Lemma 5. The group $G$ contains a normal subgroup of every prime power order dividing the order of $G$.  (This follows from Lemmas 2,3,4.)

Now if $m$ is any divisor of $|G|$, we can find normal subgroups of every maximal prime power order dividing $m$ (by Lemma 5), and by taking their direct product, we get a normal subgroup of order $m$.